# Prompt customization not working for ksh

Tags: bash, sh, zsh, ksh, prompt

I have customized my prompt as follows:

```
PS1="\e[0;34m\u\e[m@\e[0;31m\h\e[m: \e[0;33m${PWD##*/}\e[m$: "
```

Here is an image showing the result:

[image: Here is an image showing the result]

I am happy with it and it works as intended with sh, bash and zsh. However, as soon as I switch to "ksh" it gives me this as the prompt:

```
e[0;34mue[m@e[0;31mhe[m: e[0;33ma922100e[m$:
```

How can I get the formatting to work "globally", regardless of the shell I am running?

Comment: Read the documentation for each shell you intent to use and configure the feature for each one in a way proper for it. Sorry, it is rather vague answer, but basically this is what you need to do.

Comment: BTW, Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Enjoy.

Comment: You could try something like this SO question suggested: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42402 ( PS1=$( echo -e "PROMPT_VAL" );

Comment: If only a ksh expert can answer your question, please don't use `zsh`, `bash` and `sh` tags.

Comment: @Coder_Man, `echo -e` doing anything other than emitting `-e` on output is not just an extension to POSIX, but a *violation*. The standards-compliant alternative (which `ksh` supports) is `printf '%b'`.

Comment: @Coder_Man, ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections. Note also that the standards-compliant way to write an escape sequence is `\033` (the octal version of `\x1b`).

Comment: I'm surprised to learn that `ksh` doesn't provide much at all in the way of prompt escapes (nothing aside from POSIX `!` for the command number).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Okay! I added all tags since the thing here is to get it to work for any environment (ksh, zsh, sh, bash, etc.).

Comment: @OskarNorman, that's not really a reasonable request. POSIX doesn't specify these escapes (that they work in your implementation of `sh` is an accident of that specific implementation, not a guarantee), so there isn't guaranteed to *exist* any answer that works everywhere.

Comment: Literally, the **only** guarantees about PS1 that apply across all shells are those given in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html, and those guarantees say nothing about any of these escapes. So if your question is if there's a guaranteed-portable value, rather than if there's a value that works on ksh, then the answer is "no such value exists".

Comment: @OskarNorman, ...so, I'd suggest that you [edit] the question to make it clear which of these things you're asking. If you're asking for a guaranteed-portable-everywhere answer, then I can add "there exists none" as an answer (and back it up with authoritative references); whereas if you're waiting for a ksh answer, you need to wait for an expert in ksh (and should remove the other tags).

Answer (score 0):

As is your prompt isn't updated when changing directory because of `${PWD##*/}` inside double quotes is expanded when initializing PS1.

There are many ways to solve it maybe the following can work depending on ksh version.

```
csi=$'\e['
# or 
# csi=$(printf '\e[')
PS1="${csi}0;34m$(whoami)${csi}m@${csi}31m$(hostname)${csi}m: ${csi}33m"'${PWD##*/}'"${csi}m$: "
```

Comment: Is `printf -v` available in ksh? I was under the impression that was a bashism, since ksh93 recognizes `val=$(printf ...)` as a special case and skips the fork.

Comment: It was to avoid sub-shell and was checking but unfortunately not: 
   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf (ctrl+f ksh), updating

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: ok, that's new for me; could you explain the csi assignment; "RTFM" is acceptable if you can provide a link to which FMTR? thanks

Comment: I understand '\e' represents an escape, but not understanding the leading $

Comment: @markp, re: `$''`, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings. In standard single quotes, backslashes are literals, so `'\t'` is a string of length 2 (a backslash followed by a `t`), whereas `$'\t'` is a string of length 1 (a tab). This is a non-POSIX extension, but it's one that ksh supports.